# DateTime php return a wrong date

Tags: php, datetime, licensing

I'm using the PHP `DateTime` class to generate a date for a custom licensing system. While I'm debugging it, I've noted that the date time are always wrong, it will be `5-dec-2018` but now we are in November, and this date will be the same also for the `expiration_date`.

How i can fix this issue? I need to add 30 days to the start date of the trial period.

Here is the code.

```
class Activator {

  private $uuid;
  private $keygen;
  private $licence_code;

  public static function generateLicence($uuid) {

    if (!file_exists(ABSPATH.'/DataStorage/.licence')) {
        $start_date = new DateTime();
        $time_zone = $start_date->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('Europe/Rome'));
        $trial_date = $start_date->add(new DateInterval('P30D'));
        $end_date = $trial_date->format('d-M-Y');
        $machine_uuid = bin2hex($uuid);
        $licence_code = base64_encode($machine_uuid);

        $licence_file = array(
          'uuid' => $machine_uuid,
          'activation_date' => $time_zone->format('d-M-Y'),
          #'trial_version' => true,
          #'expire_date' => $end_date,
          #'licence_code' => $licence_code
        );

        $w = file_put_contents(ABSPATH.'/DataStorage/.licence', json_encode($licence_file));
        echo $w;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the expected behavior, as you `add()` to the date (by doing `$start_date->add(...)` - this modifies the original object `$start_date`.

You can solve this a few different ways, although the easiest way is just to create a new instance entirely with the 30 days added directly in the construct. You can also set the timezone as the second parameter of `new DateTime()`.

```
$timezone    = new DateTimeZone('Europe/Rome');
$start_date  = new DateTime("now", $timezone);
$trial_date  = new DateTime("+30 days", $timezone);
```

- [PHP.net on `new DateTime()`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.construct.php)
- [PHP.net on `DateTime::add()`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.add.php)

See this [live demo](https://3v4l.org/RfEBM).

Comment: It work perfectly, thanks for your answer,I was not considering the fact that the original `DateTime` object is modified when using the `DateTime::add()` function. I can also omit the timezone right?

Comment: Yes, you do not have to specify the timezone unless it should differ from the servers timezone.